# Show translation invariance from axioms

Tags: convex-analysis, axioms, risk-assessment

In [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr206-RiskTutorial_INFORMS2007.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ertr/papers/rtr206-RiskTutorial_INFORMS2007.pdf), Rockafellar defines a coherent risk measure in the following way:

$\rho : \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty]$ *is a coherent measure of risk in the basic sense* if

- **Constantness:** $\rho(C) = C $ for all constants $C$,
- **Convexity:** $\rho( \lambda X + (1-\lambda)X') \leq \lambda \rho(X) + (1-\lambda)\rho(X')\quad$ for $0\le\lambda\le 1$,
- **Monotonicity:**   $\rho(X) \leq \rho(X')$ when $X \leq X'$,
- **Closedness:** $\rho(X) \leq 0$ when $\|X_k - X \|_ 2 \rightarrow 0 $ with $\rho(X_k) \leq 0$.
- **Homogeneity:** $\rho(\lambda X) = \lambda \rho(X),$ when $ \lambda >0 $

These axioms are slightly different than other definitions, and in particular the axiom of translation invariance is not included (but closedness is), cf. for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_risk_measure#Translation_invariance.

I wonder: Can we really derive translation invariance (ie., $\rho(X + m) = \rho(X)+m$, when $m \in \mathbb{R}$ ) from the axioms above? It is clear that:
\begin{align}
  \rho(X + m) \leq \rho(X) + m, 
\end{align}
for $m \in \mathbb{R}$ by axiom 1 and 2 and 3. But this does not show equality. Is it possible to derive the opposite inequality
$\rho(X) + m \leq \rho(X+m)$, or in some other way show $\rho(X + m) = \rho(X) + m$, or is simply not translation invariance a feature of these axioms?

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing this some more, I wonder if the following argument is simply enough:
Let $X$ be a random variable, $m > 0$ a constant. Then,
\begin{align}
\rho(X) &= \rho(\frac{1}{2}( 2X + 2m) - \frac{1}{2}2m ) \\ 
&\leq \rho(\frac{1}{2}( 2X + 2m)) - m \\
& \leq \rho(X) +m -m \\
&= \rho(X), 
\end{align}
giving
\begin{align}
\rho(X) +m \leq \rho(X +m) \leq + \rho(X) +m.
\end{align}

Comment: Does the axiom of convexity not require $\lambda\in[0,1]$? How did you get your first inequality ? Also it seems that $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ should exchanged on the RHS in your  definition of convexity in the question.

Comment: In the first inequality, $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ gives $\rho(\lambda(2X + 2m) + (1-\lambda)2m) \leq \lambda \rho(2X + 2m) + (1-\lambda)\rho(-2m) = \rho(X+m) -m $ through axioms 1, 2 and 5 I thought? Perhaps I am missing something?  I agree about the order of the lambdas in the definition, my mistake!

Comment: Is it not $\rho(\lambda(2X+2m)+(1-\lambda)2m)\le\lambda\rho(2X+2m)+(1-\lambda)\rho(+2m)\,?$ I don't see where your $-2m$ comes from. Your edit of the convexity inequality above is still wrong. I'll suggest a fix.

Comment: Forgive my slowness :-) Which -2m? The right hand side of the first equality? Or in the last step? There, $m + \rho(X) \leq \rho(X + m) \leq \rho(X) + m$ was gathered from adding $m$ throughout the inequality. 

Thank you for the edit suggestion, again you were right!

Comment: The $-2m$ in $\rho(-2m)$ where I think it should be $\rho(+2m)\,.$ In other words on the RHS of the inequality everyone of us wrote down in two comments.

Comment: Put $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$. $\rho(X) = \rho(\frac{1}{2}(2X + 2m) - \frac{1}{2} 2m) = \rho(\lambda (2X + 2m) +(1-\lambda) \cdot -2m)$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128505/discussion-between-user2005142-and-kurt-g).